# QImage in QT c++ Console Application

Tags: c++, qt, console

I need to create qimage in QT console application like below
 **QImage  img = QImage( 640, 480, QImage::Format_RGB888 );**

But I received the issue below

error: undefined reference to `QImage::QImage()'

Kindly suggest me to solve this problem

Comment: Please show the actual code that causes the error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (with emphasis on the minimal part), as well as a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the errors you get from the shown code. And if possible also point out where in the shown code you get the errors (using comments in the code). Lastly please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: QImage img = QImage( 640, 480, QImage::Format_RGB888 );if( ! m_Image.isNull() )                    
                          
    m_Image.save(imgpath); In the first line itself i got undefined reference issue

Comment: Are you sure you're linking with `libQt5Gui.so` (or whatever the equivalent is on your platform)?

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) clearly states QImage needs the `Gui` module.

Comment: Im using Console application, the below is my .pro file QT += core
QT -= gui

Comment: You can link with the gui library without making it a console application.

Comment: @Lakshmy Again, please ***[edit]*** your question to include important details (such as code or libraries used). They do not belong in comments.

Comment: can you please post the pro file.

Comment: A console program is not supposed to display images, just text.

Comment: @NicolasDusart But it could load an image and do some processing on it, then save it back to disk.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the terms Qt and console still let assume you don't link against QtGui library, the questions should be rewritten as it is misleading. QImage is not usable in a "core" Qt application.

Comment: Remove the`QT -= gui` (or replace or by `QT += gui` to be sure)